# Poner Colores a Distintos Nodos en una Red

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, graphviz, python-networkx

Hola a toda la comunidad,

Les platico un poco de lo que estoy realizando. Tengo una tabla con las siguientes columnas como información: "Fuente del Reporte", "Reporte" y "Usuario del Reporte" (tienen otros nombres en el
`dataframe`, pero conceptualmente eso es lo que significan):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De esa información cree exitosamente una red usando la librería `netwokx` y el framework de visualización `pyvis`. Adjunto el código:

```
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
from networkx.drawing.nx_agraph import graphviz_layout
import ipywidgets as widgets
from ipywidgets import interact, interact_manual

#Generar Grafo

df1.insert(1, 'ORIGEN', 'ORIGEN')
paths = df1.loc[:,'ORIGEN':].stack().groupby(level=0).agg(list).values.tolist()
G = nx.DiGraph()
for path in paths:
    nx.add_path(G, path) 

@interact_manual
def grafo(grafo=['neato','dot', 'twopi', 'fdp', 'sfdp', 'circo']):
        #return df.loc[df[column] > x]
    # Posibilidades para parametro "prog": 'neato',‘dot’, ‘twopi’, ‘fdp’, ‘sfdp’, ‘circo’
    pos = graphviz_layout(G, prog= grafo)
    plt.figure(figsize=(20, 20))

    nx.draw(G, pos= pos,
            node_size=40, 
            alpha=0.5, 
            node_color="blue", 
            with_labels=True,
            arrows=True)

    plt.savefig("dendograma.pdf")
    plt.axis("equal")
    plt.show()
    return 
def draw_graph3(networkx_graph,notebook=True,output_filename='graph.html',show_buttons=True,only_physics_buttons=False):
    """
   Esta función acepta un objeto gráfico "networkx",
      lo convierte en un objeto de red "pyvis" conservando sus atributos de nodo y borde,
      y devuelve y guarda una visualización de red dinámica.
    
    Atributos de nodo validos:
        "size", "value", "title", "x", "y", "label", "color".
        
        (Para más información: https://pyvis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/documentation.html#pyvis.network.Network.add_node)
        
    Atributos de vertices validos:
        "arrowStrikethrough", "hidden", "physics", "title", "value", "width"
        
        (Para más información: https://pyvis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/documentation.html#pyvis.network.Network.add_edge)
        
    
    Argumentos:
        networkx_graph: El gráfico para convertir y mostrar
        notebook: ¿Quieres desplegar la visualización en Jupyter Notebook?
        output_filename: Ubicación donde se guardara la red convertida
        show_buttons: ¿Mostrar botones en la versión guardada de la red?
        only_physics_buttons: ¿Mostrar parametros para modificar la red?
    """
    
    # Importacion de librerias
    from pyvis import network as net
    
    # Crear una red de pyvis
    pyvis_graph = net.Network(notebook=notebook,heading='Fuentes Banco Sabadell', directed = True)
    
    # Para cada nodo y sus atributos en el gráfico networkx
    for node,node_attrs in networkx_graph.nodes(data=True):
        pyvis_graph.add_node(str(node),**node_attrs, size = 10)
        
    # para cada vertice y sus atributos en el gráfico networkx
    for source,target,edge_attrs in networkx_graph.edges(data=True):
        # si el valor / ancho no se especifica directamente y se especifica el peso, establezca 'value' en 'weight'
        if not 'value' in edge_attrs and not 'width' in edge_attrs and 'weight' in edge_attrs:
            # colocar en la clave 'value' el peso del vertice
            edge_attrs['value']=edge_attrs['weight']
        # agregar el vértice
        pyvis_graph.add_edge(str(source),str(target),**edge_attrs, arrowStrikethrough = True )
        
    # agregar botones
    if show_buttons:
        if only_physics_buttons:
            pyvis_graph.show_buttons(filter_=['physics'])
        else:
            pyvis_graph.show_buttons()
    
    # regresar grafo y guardar
    return pyvis_graph.show(output_filename)

# Llamada a la función
draw_graph3(G, only_physics_buttons=True)
```

Dándome como salida la siguiente red:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo lo que quiero lograr es que el nodo origen, tenga un color, los nodos de las fuentes tengan un color distinto, los nodos de los reportes otro distinto y finalmente los nodos últimos de los usuarios un color distinto para mejorar el gráfico. ¿Alguna idea de como lo podría lograr?

¡Saludos!

Comment: Sería interesante que proporcionaras un enlace a tus datos (una excel o una csv serviría) para poder recrear el dataframe, y con él probar tu código para después modificarlo y añadirle los colores que pides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final solo tuve que agregar estas lineas dentro de la función `draw_graph3` para obtener lo que buscaba:

```
# Para cada nodo y sus atributos en el gráfico networkx
for node,node_attrs in networkx_graph.nodes(data=True):
    if node in origen:
        color = 'black'
    elif node in fuentes:
        color = 'blue'
    elif node in reportes:
        color = 'lightblue'
    else:
        color = 'lightgrey'
    pyvis_graph.add_node(str(node),**node_attrs, size = 10, color = color)
```

Este fue el increíble resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]